# convert string to array when multiple deliminator are encountered

Tags: php, string

i want to convert string into array when `comma or semicolon` is encountered.

for example  a string `a , b ; c , d ; e` will be converted into

```
[0] = a 
[1] = b
[2] = c
[3] = d
[4] = e
```

i tried using `explode` and that works fine so far but i am able to specify only 
**one deliminator** like `explode(",",$str)` while i want to use two deliminators. i.e.
comma and semicolon.

i don't know if it is possible to specify a pattern in explode function as a first parameter.

Comment: Down voter is little confused i guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$pieces = preg_split('@[,;]@', 'a,b;c,d;e');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it:

```
$delimeters = array(',',';');

$arr = str_split($str);
/*
[0] = a 
[1] = ,
[2] = b
[3] = ;
[4] = c
[5] = ,
[6] = d ...
*/

$filterd = array_filter($arr, function($elem){ return (!in_array($elem , $delimeters)) });
```

Basicly , we split the string to array so each character is an element in the array.
After that , we are filtering the array to retun only characters which are not delimeters (just update the delimiters array).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$var_save = strtok($string,',;');

echo $var_save;
```